# SQL: How to display a column not in group by expression?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code:

```
select O.ONO
from Customers C, Odetails Od, Orders O, Parts P
where P.PNO=Od.PNO and Od.ONO=O.ONO and O.CNO=C.CNO
group by O.ONO
order by sum(Od.QTY*P.PRICE)desc;
```

However, instead of selecting the `O.ONO` column, I need to select the `C.CNAME` from a different table. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You should join with a modern style -- by be 30 years out of date?

Comment: @user2853262 what Hogan means is that the join syntax of `... from Customers C INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.CNO = O.CNO...` conveys the intent of the query much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is a list of Customer Names ordered by the sum of their orders then just change your query from

```
select O.ONO
...
group by O.ONO
```

to

```
select C.CName
...
group by C.CName
```

This will display the customer name and the order number. NOTE: This will repeat the customer name as many times as there are orders for that customer

Also, my preferred style of SQL queries is

```
select C.CName
from Customers C
    INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.CNO = O.CNO
    INNER JOIN Odetails OD ON O.ONO = OD.ONO
    INNER JOIN Parts P ON OID.PNO = P.PNO
where P.PNO=Od.PNO and Od.ONO=O.ONO and O.CNO=C.CNO
group by C.CName
order by sum(Od.QTY*P.PRICE)desc;
```

An additional suggestion to clarify your code. *(please note: I'm not an oracle person)*, in my company (SqlServer) generally you would have the table named after the entity, with the primary key being just `Id`, and then any property named without a prefix. For instance does `OID` refer to `OrderId` or `OfficeId`?

**EG:**

Customer:

- Id
- Name

Order:

- Id
- CustomerId

Then your queries are much more readable:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Customer
    INNER JOIN Order ON Customer.Id = Order.CustomerId
WHERE ...
ORDER BY Customer.Name
```

Comment: My only issue is that I need to group them by `O.ONO` because Orders have multiple part numbers associated with them (the primary key for Odetails is `ONO` and `PNO`) not sure if this makes much sense

Comment: So include O.ONO in both the select and the group by clause

Comment: @user2853262 actually, do you *just* want to display the customers in the list? Or *also* display the order numbers in the list?

Comment: I got it to work @Nathan Koop. Sorry for being a noob, just trying to learn on my own.

Comment: Yea I did @Nathan Koop. I also did some reading up on Inner Joins and changed my code to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this,

```
select C.CNAME from Customers C, Odetails Od, Orders O, Parts P where P.PNO=Od.PNO and Od.ONO=O.ONO and O.CNO=C.CNO group by C.CNAME order by sum(Od.QTY*P.PRICE) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The select statement will select the column specified

```
SELECT C.CNAME
FROM Customers C, Odetails Od, Orders O, Parts P
WHERE P.PNO=Od.PNO and Od.ONO=O.ONO and O.CNO=C.CNO
GROUP BY C.CNAME
ORDER BY sum(Od.QTY*P.PRICE)desc;
```

If you wish to still keep O.ONO column selected as well

```
SELECT C.CNAME, O.ONO
FROM Customers C, Odetails Od, Orders O, Parts P
WHERE P.PNO=Od.PNO and Od.ONO=O.ONO and O.CNO=C.CNO
GROUP BY C.CNAME
ORDER BY sum(Od.QTY*P.PRICE)desc;
```